# GTK Button constrain proportions

Tags: c, gtk, gtk4

I have a bunch of GTK buttons in a GTK Flowbox, and am using the CSS border-radius property to make them round and background-image for the background. Unfortunately, they then appear as ovals, as in picrel below. What can I do so that the button would always have height equal to width, thus maintaining the shape of a perfect circle?

[image]

A MRE as requested:
C file:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 600

GtkWidget * stop;
int num_stops; 

static void stop_toggle (GtkToggleButton *source, gpointer user_data) {
    //have to use set child here
    if (gtk_toggle_button_get_active(source)) {
        gtk_widget_set_name(GTK_WIDGET(source), "stop_button_pressed");
    }
    else {
        gtk_widget_set_name(GTK_WIDGET(source), "stop_button");
    }
}  

static void make_toggles (GtkWidget * window) {
    GtkWidget * stop_flow;
    short i; 

    stop_flow = gtk_flow_box_new();
    
    //initialise stops on this panel
    char label[7]; label[0] = '\0';
    for (i = 0; i < num_stops; i++) {
        sprintf(label, "%d", i);
        stop = gtk_toggle_button_new_with_label(label);
        gtk_widget_set_name(stop, "stop_button");
        
        gtk_flow_box_append(GTK_FLOW_BOX(stop_flow), stop);
        g_signal_connect(stop, "toggled", G_CALLBACK(stop_toggle), NULL);
    }
    gtk_flow_box_set_column_spacing(GTK_FLOW_BOX(stop_flow), 15);
    gtk_flow_box_set_row_spacing(GTK_FLOW_BOX(stop_flow), 10);
    gtk_flow_box_set_selection_mode(GTK_FLOW_BOX(stop_flow), GTK_SELECTION_NONE);
    
    gtk_widget_set_name(stop_flow, "window_main");
    gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (window), stop_flow);
}
static void app_startup(GtkApplication* app) {
    //use this to figure out number of stops and pistons from the LCS app
    num_stops = 16; 
}
static void activate (GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data) {
    GtkWidget *window;

    window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Left Panel");
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 800, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    make_toggles(window);
    
    GtkCssProvider * cssProvider = gtk_css_provider_new();
    gtk_css_provider_load_from_path(cssProvider, "/your_location/GTK/styling2.css");
    gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_display(gtk_widget_get_display(window), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(cssProvider),
                                                                    GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
    gtk_widget_show (window);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    app = gtk_application_new("lcs.console", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
    g_signal_connect(app, "startup", G_CALLBACK(app_startup), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref (app);

    return status;
}
```

With Css file:

```
w_main {
    background-color: grey;
}

#stop_button {
    background-color: white;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: xx-large;
}
#stop_button_pressed {
    background-color: yellow;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: xx-large;
}
```

And you may compile the CSS file on linux via
gcc -Wall `pkg-config --cflags gtk4` file.c `pkg-config --libs gtk4` .

Comment: Please _edit_ your _question_ and produce an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We'd like a _single_ `.c` file that compiles cleanly and demonstrates the problem [rather than background images, just set solid colors]. We might like to download, compile, and run your code. Also, what is the window geometry? And, what is the _screen_ geometry? (i.e.) We'd like to know the screen aspect ration and, possibly, the _pixel_ aspect ratio. As a rule, whenever a circle comes out as an oval, it's related to aspect ratio.

Comment: Also, what pixel format are you using? 8 bit colormap, 16 bit true color, 24 bit RGB/BGR (8 bits/color), or 32 bit? Your ovals appear to be approx. 2x taller than wider. (e.g.) If the surface expected 8 bit pixels, but you gave it 16 bit pixels but didn't tell it, this _might_ be the issue.

Comment: Alright I added an MRE. I do not know what you mean by pixel format I just used the css background-image command.

Answer (score 2):

I tried out your code, and in testing out different quantities of buttons, the issue seemed to circle around the behavior of the gtk_flow_box widget.  As more buttons were added, the size and distortion of the buttons grew.  No matter what I tried, the program would not allow for the window to be reduced in size to make the oval buttons look like circular buttons.

I don't know if it is mandatory that you utilize the GTK flow box, but if not, you might try utilizing a GTK grid box instead.  Following is a refactored version of your program with container references changed from a flow box to a grid box.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 300

GtkWidget * stop;
int num_stops;

static void stop_toggle (GtkToggleButton *source, gpointer user_data)
{
    //have to use set child here
    if (gtk_toggle_button_get_active(source))
    {
        gtk_widget_set_name(GTK_WIDGET(source), "stop_button_pressed");
    }
    else
    {
        gtk_widget_set_name(GTK_WIDGET(source), "stop_button");
    }
}

static void make_toggles (GtkWidget * window)
{
    GtkWidget * stop_grid;                                      /* Revised name to pertain to a grid box */
    short i;

    stop_grid = gtk_grid_new();
    gtk_grid_set_column_spacing(GTK_GRID(stop_grid), 10);
    gtk_grid_set_row_spacing(GTK_GRID(stop_grid), 10);

    //initialise stops on this panel
    char label[7];
    label[0] = '\0';

    /*gtk_flow_box_set_column_spacing(GTK_FLOW_BOX(stop_flow), 0);
    gtk_flow_box_set_row_spacing(GTK_FLOW_BOX(stop_flow), 0);
    gtk_flow_box_set_selection_mode(GTK_FLOW_BOX(stop_flow), GTK_SELECTION_NONE);*/

    gtk_widget_set_name(stop_grid, "window_main");

    for (i = 0; i < num_stops; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < num_stops; j++)                 /* Create a 4 x 4 grid of buttons */
        {
            sprintf(label, "%d", i * num_stops + j + 1);
            stop = gtk_toggle_button_new_with_label(label);
            gtk_widget_set_name(stop, "stop_button");
            gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(stop_grid), stop, j, i * num_stops, 1, 1);
            //gtk_flow_box_append(GTK_FLOW_BOX(stop_flow), stop);
            g_signal_connect(stop, "toggled", G_CALLBACK(stop_toggle), NULL);
        }
    }

    gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (window), stop_grid);
}
static void app_startup(GtkApplication* app)
{
    //use this to figure out number of stops and pistons from the LCS app
    num_stops = 4;                                                          /* Revised for unit testing */
}
static void activate (GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget *window;

    window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Left Panel");
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 300, WINDOW_HEIGHT);  /* Revised for unit testing */
    make_toggles(window);

    GtkCssProvider * cssProvider = gtk_css_provider_new();
    gtk_css_provider_load_from_path(cssProvider, "styling2.css");           /* Revised for unit testing */
    gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_display(gtk_widget_get_display(window), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(cssProvider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
    gtk_widget_show (window);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    app = gtk_application_new("lcs.console", 0);                            /* Revised for unit testing */
    g_signal_connect(app, "startup", G_CALLBACK(app_startup), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref (app);

    return status;
}
```

Along with the code refactoring, the style sheet was revised a bit to add in some padding.

```
#window_main {
    background-color: #c5dbe0;
    padding:10px;
}

#stop_button {
    background-color: white;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: xx-large;
    min-width:40px;
    min-height:40px;
    padding:10px;
    border:20px;
}
#stop_button_pressed {
    background-color: yellow;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: xx-large;
    min-width:40px;
    min-height:40px;
    padding:10px;
    border:20px;
}
```

With those bits of refactoring and refinements, a window with circular buttons was able to be produced.

[image: Sample Button Grid]

Again, if it is not mandatory that you utilize a GTK flow box, you might try out these tweaks and see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: Interesting, the padding property was the final touch needed to make them perfectly round. I suppose if I am not able to find a FlowBox solution I will go with this

Comment: My main concern with a GTK Grid approach is that it is not dynamic, i.e. in order to fill the whole screen I need to manually set the min-height and min-width property depending on the number of stops.